# Android AdMob Real Ad Unit ID in Beta & Alpha channels

Tags: android, google-play, admob, ads

My android application has some admob ads. I am testing my admob in Google Play store Alpha & Beta channel.

**My question is:**

Can I use REAL admob ad unit ids when I deploy my app into Google play store Alpha & Beta channels? Does it violate google play policy?

I read this in Google admob:

> Do I need to use test ads? Yes. It is against AdMob policy to use live
>   ads during development, and doing so could cause the suspension of
>   your AdMob account.

BUT it seems not very clear to me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use ads in beta (and alpha) testing.

> Do I need to use test ads? Yes. It is against AdMob policy to use live ads during development, and doing so could cause the suspension of your AdMob account.

This just means when you are coding your app and putting it on your device to test it, you cannot have live ads.

Comment: Yes, alpha and beta is for testing. It is not development.