# Is it allowed to use Admob ads during alpha or beta testing in Google Play?

Tags: android, admob

I am going to upload my app as alpha testing in google play, but I wonder...

Is it correct to enable real Admob ads (no test ads) now in my app during alpha testing? Or should I add them later, when I upload my apk for production in google play?

Comment: There is no mention of putting ads in alpha / beta testing in google's policy document https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2753860?hl=en , so you should be ok, however always there is chance of users clicking on ads accidently. If Alpha testing is for closed group, would recommend to add test ads

Comment: this link will help more - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29731424/android-admob-real-ad-unit-id-in-beta-alpha-channels

Comment: @AmodGokhale No the alpha testing is for open group

Comment: you should be ok to use real ads. Both links above doesn't mention not having them in alpha channel

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about policies are customer support, which is off-topic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it ok to add admob ads during alpha testing in google play?

Yes it is. There is nothing that says you cannot do it during alpha and beta. Meaning having ads in alpha/beta is fine, doing anything against the Admob policy(e.g. getting people to press your ads) is still against the policy